# Pfgplots Layered Opacity

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, transparency

So i have a line, with an overlaying scatter plot, generated by this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot [blue, domain = 1:2000, line width = 1pt] 
            {exp(-0.176385)*x^0.492486 };
        \addplot [orange!20, opacity = 0.5, only marks] table {values.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Generated puctire]
My problem with this, is that where there are many dots, the line in the background becomes invisible. I find it hard to explain, but I want to add opacity after the circles have been plotted, so that the opacities doesn't add up.

In graphics terms, I want to have all the circles with opacity 1 on a layer with opacity 0.5. Is this possible?

(nb! I dont want to have the line overlay the circles, the line should be behind as is now).

Comment: Check the `blend mode` options in the PGF/Ti*k*Z manual

Answer (score 1):

One can simply draw the blue line twice, the second time transparent.

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[set layers]
        \addplot [blue, domain = 1:2000, line width = 1pt] 
            {exp(-0.176385)*x^0.492486};
        \addplot [orange!10, only marks,domain=0:2000,samples=100]
            {exp(-0.176385)*x^0.492486+rand};
        \pgfonlayer{axis foreground}
        \addplot [blue, domain = 1:2000, line width = 1pt,opacity=.5] 
            {exp(-0.176385)*x^0.492486};
        \endpgfonlayer
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a high resolution snapshot. Is this what you want?

[image]

Comment: Nonetheless, @percusse's suggestion is better.

Comment: That was a perfect solution! I agree that as percusse suggest, it's possible (and maybe a better solution) to use blend modes, but this is a very good idea. Simple but effective concept, thank you.